# PHP: display in "Today" only, not in "Yesterday" too

Tags: php

```
$today = time() - (3600*24);
$Yday = time() - (3600*48);

$getMsgsToday = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_msgs WHERE uID = '$USER' AND date > $today");
$countToday = mysql_num_rows($getMsgsToday);

$getMsgsYday = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_msgs WHERE uID = '$USER' AND date > $Yday");
$countYday = mysql_num_rows($getMsgsYday);
```

This is my code for displaying messages latest 24 hours and 48 hours(yesterday).

I got two while for the queries(yesterday and today).

Now if you have something within 24 hours, it will also display in the yesterday while().

I only wish to show yesterday´s messages, with this I mean the 24 hours before today´s 24 hours.

How can I do this, so I dont get these duplicates?

Comment: Is your date a date or a datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`BETWEEN … AND …`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) to select only those between 48 hours and 24 hours ago:

```
"SELECT * FROM users_msgs WHERE uID = '$USER' AND date BETWEEN $Yday AND $today"
```

Comment: Could you also use the NOW() sql function to get the current date rather than manually calculating it in php?

Comment: The [`NOW` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) is not returning a Unix timestamp but the time in MySQL’s time format. But the [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) can be used instead.

Comment: Yes you could, but there was some story someone told me about it, so I rather not to, just in case... anyway nice solution gumbo, one last question, how should I do if I only want to show all msgs AFTER the 48 hours?

Comment: @user457827: What do you mean by after? More or less than 48 hour ago?

Comment: @user457827: Use `… date < $Yday`. Note that `date BETWEEN $Yday AND $today` is equal to `date >= $Yday AND date <= $today`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$getMsgsYday = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_msgs WHERE uID = '$USER' AND date BETWEEN $Yday and $today");
```